# iOS Share Extension Only Shows in Safari

Tags: ios, ios8-share-extension, ios-extensions

I am testing an iOS share extension I'm building for an iPhone app. The share extension only appears in the share sheet for Safari. It doesn't show up in any 3rd party apps like Alien Blue or even any other 1st party apps like News. Is this because the app has not yet been released? Or is it a problem with my code?

Comment: And what is your code?

Comment: Can you share your plist? Look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427579/how-can-run-share-extension-in-safari-and-chrome . It can be useful.

Comment: Its something in your code. you don't need app on App Store to appear in third party apps. please share plist file.

Comment: Please share your Plist file so we can get idea why its not working.

Comment: @AttilaTheFun What do you want to share? What does your `NSExtensionActivationRule` look like?

Answer (score 2):

I have the following NSExtensionActivationRule set. My extension appears in Safari, Firefox and Chrome.

```
<key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <string>SUBQUERY (
                extensionItems,
                $extensionItem,
                SUBQUERY (
                $extensionItem.attachments,
                $attachment,
                (
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.plain-text"
                )
                ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count
                ).@count == 1</string>
```