# How can run Share Extension in safari and chrome?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

After running app, if i open the share extension in safari it's not working. But if i run on chrome,then open in safar it is working. Can you give me  solution for running share extension in  both browsers. In .plist i'm using this code.

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingFile</key>
            <string>DemoPreprocessor</string>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
        <string>MainInterface</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is mine.It works.

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>20</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
    <string>MainInterface</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: Don't need to include DemoPreprocessor ?

Comment: @HituBansal It worked on latest chrome.And you can try both.

Comment: Thank you so much! Took forever to find this.

Comment: @Charles Is this work in chrome? I try, but it don't work

Comment: @Denis Yes, it is working for me in Chrome, Firefox, and all the other major browsers I've tried.

Comment: @Charles Can you help me with my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38637484/ios-share-extension-is-not-working-in-chrome I try but always i can't see my app in chrome share menu. In safari share menu my app exist.